# Can we convert a string to function name and call that function?

Tags: java, string, function

Student.java

```
class Student {
    String name;
    String address;
}
```

We have getters and setters for name and address.
Now if we want to call functions based on some variable like:

Demo.java

```
class Demo {
    Student s = new Student();
    String var = "name";
}
```

Now if I want to call `getName` or `getAddress` based on value assigned to var, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You can write a switch statement or you can use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is called reflection. Here is a very single example of calling a getter and setter, more explanation in the code.

For simplicity, this is the Student class

```
class Student {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And this is how to call getter and setter.

```
    try {
        Student student = new Student();
        String propertyName = "name";

        //creates setName from "set" and "name"
        String setterName = "set" + propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1);
        // we are looking for method with name setterName which has one String argument
        Method setter = student.getClass().getMethod(setterName, String.class);
        //call setName, pass Bob as an argument
        setter.invoke(student, "Bob");


        //creates setName from "get" and "name"
        String getterName = "get" + propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1);
        //we are looking for method with name getterName having no input arguments
        Method getter = student.getClass().getMethod(getterName);

        //calls getter, gets Bob
        String retrievedName = getter.invoke(student).toString();
        System.out.println("Hello " + retrievedName + "!");


        //String is the method argument type
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to get field value, like this:

```
Student S = new Student();
String var = "name";

try {
    Object value = S.getClass().getDeclaredField(var).get(S);
    System.out.println(value);

} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you have not access to the field or the specified field not exists then some exception throws, and the catch part will be executed.

Comment: also, you could use `Student.class` instead of `S.getclass()`